# Create a type for each Integer in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like to create a data type in Haskell that represents the integers mod `n`, and which is an instance of `Num` to help perform simple modular arithmetic operations. My first attempt at this looked like this

```
data Z n e = El n e
instance (Show n, Show e) => Show (Z n e) where
    show (El n e) = show e ++ " (mod " ++ show n ++ ")"

instance (Integral k, Integral e) => Num (Z k e) where
    (+) (El n a) (El m b) = El n (mod (a + b) n)
    (-) (El n a) (El m b) = El n (mod (a - b) n)
    (*) (El n a) (El m b) = El n (mod (a * b) n)
    negate (El n a) = El n (mod (0 - a) n)
    abs (El n a) = El n a
    signum (El n a) = El n a
    fromInteger i = -- problematic...
```

This compiles but is problematic not only because its unclear how to implement `fromInteger` since `k` is out of scope, but also because it is permissible to add an integer `mod 4` with an integer `mod 5` without a type error. In my second attempt I tried to resolve these issues

```
data Z n = El Integer
instance (Show n) => Show (Z n) where
    show (El n e) = show e ++ " (mod " ++ show n ++ ")"

instance (Integral k) => Num (Z k) where
    (+) (El k a) (El k b) = El k (mod (a + b) k)
    (-) (El k a) (El k b) = El k (mod (a - b) k)
    (*) (El k a) (El k b) = El k (mod (a * b) k)
    negate (El k a) = El k (mod (0 - a) k)
    abs (El k a) = El k a
    signum (El k a) = El k a
    fromInteger i = El (fromIntegral i) k
```

but I am running into trouble implementing the `Num` interface because of conflicting definitions of `k` which is still out of scope. How can I make such a data type in Haskell?

Comment: You need to represent the numbers at *type level*.  `Integral k` means `k` is a type which contains integer(-like thing)s, but you want to say `k` is itself an integer.  Research type-level naturals, there is a lot of material about it.

Comment: Ahh thanks thats very helpful. Part of my issue was not knowing what the proper terms are to describe this to search for.

Comment: Like [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.10.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Moduli-Class.html).

Comment: Ir [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/modular-arithmetic-1.2.1.5/docs/Data-Modular.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, the idea is to make use of a type-level representation of natural numbers, so you have separate identifiable types for 2 versus 3 versus 4, etc.  This requires an extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
```

There are two main methods for representing naturals as types.  The first is to define a recursive data type:

```
data Nat' = Z | S Nat'
```

which the `DataKinds` extension automatically lifts to the type level.  You can then use this as, among other things, a type-level tag to define a family of related but distinct types:

```
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
data Foo (n :: Nat') = Foo Int

twoFoo :: Foo (S (S Z))
twoFoo = Foo 10

threeFoo :: Foo (S (S (S Z)))
threeFoo = Foo 20

addFoos :: Foo n -> Foo n -> Foo n
addFoos (Foo x) (Foo y) = Foo (x + y)

okay = addFoos twoFoo twoFoo
bad =  addFoos twoFoo threefoo -- error: different types
```

The second is to use a built-in GHC facility that automatically lifts integer literals, like `2` and `3` to the type level.  It works much the same way:

```
import GHC.TypeLits (Nat)

data Foo (n :: Nat) = Foo Int

twoFoo :: Foo 2
twoFoo = Foo 10

threeFoo :: Foo 3
threeFoo = Foo 20

addFoos :: Foo n -> Foo n -> Foo n
addFoos (Foo x) (Foo y) = Foo (x + y)

okay = addFoos twoFoo twoFoo
bad =  addFoos twoFoo threefoo -- type error
```

When you're using naturals only to "tag" a type, it's generally more convenient to use the `GHC.TypeLits` version of `Nat`.  If you have to actually do type-level computations on the types, some computations are more easily done using the recursive version.

Since we only need the naturals as tags, we can stick with the `GHC.TypeLits` solution.  So, we'd define your data type like so:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
import GHC.TypeLits
data Z (n :: Nat) = El Integer
```

In the `Show` instance, we need to make use of some other facilities in `GHC.TypeLits` to convert the type-level `Nat` to a value-level `Integer` that we can include in the printed representation:

```
instance (KnownNat n) => Show (Z n) where
  show el@(El e) = show e ++ " (mod " ++ show (natVal el) ++ ")"
```

There's magic going on here!  The `natVal` function has signature:

```
natVal :: forall n proxy. KnownNat n => proxy n -> Integer
```

meaning that for a `"KnownNat"`, whatever that means, it can take a proxy value whose type is of form `proxy n`, and return the actual integer corresponding to the type-level argument `n`.  Fortunately, our original element has type `Z n` which fits the `proxy n` type pattern just fine, so by running `natVal el`, we get the value-level `Integer` corresponding to the type-level `n` in `Z n`.

We'll use the same magic in the `Integral` instance:

```
instance (KnownNat k) => Num (Z k) where
    (+) el@(El a) (El b) = El (mod (a + b) k) where k = natVal el
    (-) el@(El a) (El b) = El (mod (a - b) k) where k = natVal el
    (*) el@(El a) (El b) = El (mod (a * b) k) where k = natVal el
    negate el@(El a) = El (mod (0 - a) k) where k = natVal el
    abs el@(El a) = El a where k = natVal el
    signum el@(El a) = El 1
    fromInteger i = El (fromIntegral i)
```

Note that the `k` disappears from the `El` constructor, because it's not a data-level quantity.  Where needed, it can be retrieved using `natVal el` using the `KnownNat` instance.

The full program is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
import GHC.TypeLits
data Z (n :: Nat) = El Integer

instance (KnownNat n) => Show (Z n) where
  show el@(El e) = show e ++ " (mod " ++ show (natVal el) ++ ")"

instance (KnownNat k) => Num (Z k) where
    (+) el@(El a) (El b) = El (mod (a + b) k) where k = natVal el
    (-) el@(El a) (El b) = El (mod (a - b) k) where k = natVal el
    (*) el@(El a) (El b) = El (mod (a * b) k) where k = natVal el
    negate el@(El a) = El (mod (0 - a) k) where k = natVal el
    abs el@(El a) = El a where k = natVal el
    signum el@(El a) = El 1
    fromInteger i = El (fromIntegral i)
```

and it works as intended:

```
> :set -XDataKinds
> (El 2 :: Z 5) + (El 3 :: Z 5)
0 (mod 5)
> (El 2 :: Z 5) + (El 3 :: Z 7)

<interactive>:15:18: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘7’ with ‘5’
      Expected type: Z 5
        Actual type: Z 7
    • In the second argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘(El 3 :: Z 7)’
      In the expression: (El 2 :: Z 5) + (El 3 :: Z 7)
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = (El 2 :: Z 5) + (El 3 :: Z 7)
```