# Data type parametrized by constant in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, dependent-type, data-kinds, parameterized-types

I would like to define a data type in Haskell which is parametrized by an `Int` constant along the lines:

`data Q (n :: Int) = Q n (Int,Int) -- non-working code`

in order to allow me to define functions of the type:

```
addQ :: (Q n)->(Q n)->(Q n)
addQ (Q k (i1,j1)) (Q k (i2,j2))) = Q k (i1+i2,j1+j2)
```

The idea is that in this way I am able to restrict addition to `Q`'s that have the same `n`. Intuitively, it feels that this should be possible, but so far all my (admittedly newbie) attempts have stranded on the rigors of GHC.

Comment: You can do that with `Nat`, see https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#t:Nat

Comment: You can't write `Q n (Int,Int)` for the constructor since `n` is not a type. What would that mean? You can use something like `data Q (n :: Nat) = Q (Int,Int)` with the right extensions.

Answer (score 8):

As the comments say, this is possible with the DataKinds extension (technically it's possible to achieve something very similar without it, but it's very unergonomic).

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, ExplicitForAll, KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Nat)
data Q (n :: Nat) = Q Int

addQ :: forall (n :: Nat). Q n -> Q n -> Q n
addQ (Q x) (Q y) = Q (x + y)
```

---

```
let q1 = Q 1 :: Q 3
    q2 = Q 2 :: Q 3
in addQ q1 q2
-- => Q 3 :: Q 3
```

If you put the `KnownNat` constraint on `n` (also from `GHC.TypeLits`) you can also get the `n` as a regular term using the [`natVal`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.1.0/docs/GHC-TypeLits.html#v:natVal) function.

Comment: How do I "put the `KnownNat` constraint on `n`"?

Comment: @BeMuSeD `KnownNat n =>`, it's just a constraint like any other.

Comment: Just found what I needed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59222632/create-a-type-for-each-integer-in-haskell/59228880#59228880 Sorry that I had not spotted this earlier!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the hints and answer kindly supplied, I can give the answer I was looking for, including an example of how to unpack `n` from the parametrized data type.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, ExplicitForAll, KindSignatures #-}

import GHC.TypeLits (Nat,KnownNat,natVal)

data Q (n :: Nat) = Q (Int,Int)

instance (KnownNat n) => Show (Q n) where
    show q@(Q (i,j)) = "("++(show i)++","++(show j)++")::"++(show (natVal q))

addQ :: forall (n :: Nat). Q n -> Q n -> Q n
addQ (Q (i1,j1)) (Q (i2,j2)) = Q (i1+i2,j1+j2)
```

Comment: Additionally, if your goal is only to "restrict the arguments to be the same", you don't need to make it a `Nat` - you can just leave it polymorphic within the bounds of the block in which you want it to be restricted to the same thing.